# How to handle SSO in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am working on jmeter script in which I have to handle internal SSO. The service providing the access token is internally called and I can not see that while recording. Can anyone help me on that?

HTTP Authorization Manager was added during the recording session but it's not of any help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naNHu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uUr0.png)

Answer (score 1):

If your application is using [Kerberos SSO](https://medium.com/swlh/sso-with-spnego-and-kerberos-8794f8ad5162) just adding HTTP Authorization Manager will not be enough, you will need to:

1. Perform the relevant configuration in [krb5.conf](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/krb5.conf) and eventually in [jass.conf](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/jaas.conf) files (both reside in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
2. Point JMeter to these files using [`java.security.krb5.conf` and `java.security.auth.login.config` properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html) correspondingly

No one here will be able to give you the details as they're specific for your application deployment, you can use [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) as the reference and contact your application developers or your network administrators for the correct values

Comment: Thanks, i will try this

Answer (score 0):

for me this request is failing /idp/${sessionid}/resumeSAML20/idp/SSO.ping

solution : I saw doc tab under network tab under doc failing twice and third time is passing.

so imitated same in Jmeter by placing duplicate request.
so in Jmeter also it is failed twice and third one given proper response.

Note: do not forget to add cookie manager with "standard" and enable clear for each iteration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).